# some of array_unique values are undefined?

Tags: php

I'm using array_unique to remove duplicates from an array, but even though the counter is right, and the number of the elements is right, some of its elements are displayed as undefined!

```
$varietals=array_unique($varietals1);

$countVarietals = count($varietals);
```

I'm listing results with jquery

```
var Varietal = data.Varietal;
var countVarietal = data.countVarietal;
//  alert(countVarietal);
$("#selectVarietal").html("");
for(var i = 0; i < countVarietal; i++){

    $("#selectVarietal").append("<label><input type='checkbox' class='wineTypeCheck'  name='Varietal' value='"+Varietal[i]+"' />"+Varietal[i]+"</label><br />");
}
```

Anybody familiar with this?
thank u in advance!

Comment: Have you tried seeing the data in PHP itself rather than seeing in jQuery?

Comment: no, since that's placed in an empty page that contains just php script, i will try it now though

Comment: yeah it works fine in php alone, the problem is with indexing, i get it now

Comment: $varietals=array_values(array_unique($varietals1)); i had to add array_values() in order close the gap between the keys

Comment: Answer your own question and mark as right answer

Comment: then edit this question and add the answer in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  a = array("one", "two", "two", "three")
  a = array_unique(a);
  /* will lead to:
  a[0] = "one"
  a[1] = "two"
  a[3] = "three"
  */
  a = array_values(a);

   /* Now we've got:
  a[0] = "one"
  a[1] = "two"
   a[2] = "three"
  */
```

thus I needed to add array_values(), in order to close the gap

```
    $varietals=array_values(array_unique($varietals1));
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php